# R: Why is the matches function identifying 38 more words than asked to (13 are in regex)?

Tags: r, match, cpu-word

*Context:*
There are 10489 columns in the nouncount data frame--most of which are the counts of words in dictionaries. I am trying to identify and deselect 13 columns from this frame for the new frame. I have created a regex containing the 13 words I wish to leave out and was hoping to use matches to deselect columns in this regex for new one. This worked with a smaller data frame above.

*Problem:*
However, the function is overshooting and selecting 51 words, not 13.

**Code I am trying to troubleshoot:**

```
#new data frame (nouncount_ctrl) for control which removes final rain tokens
nouncount_ctrl <- nouncount %>% select(ematches(fin_rainsetregex))
```

*Code that works:*

```
nouncount_ctrl <- nouncount_ctrl %>% select(-c(cloud, clouds, drizzle, hail, mist, monsoon, rain, rainbow, rainfall, rains, sleet, storm, thunderstorm))
```

I was hoping to make the match function work to be more efficient.

Comment: Can you show what you have in `fin_rainsetregex` ? Try `nouncount_ctrl <- nouncount %>% select(-fin_rainsetregex)`

Comment: Hi @ronak Shah--thank you. I realised shortly after posting that I had not created the regex. Have now done so using the below code and it works very well! 

  fin_rainset_regex <-  paste0("^(", paste(rain_terms, collapse="|"), ")$")

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Posting in case helpful: Did not compute regex properly following creating rain_terms:

fin_rainset_regex <-  paste0("^(", paste(rain_terms, collapse="|"), ")$")